# Coset is open in a normed linear space

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(X,  \left\Vert\right.\left\Vert\right)$ be a normed linear space and $U$ be an open subset of $X$. How to prove $x+U$ is open for all $x \in X$ via open set definition?

My try: Let $y \in x+U$. Then $y=x+k$ where $k \in U$. Since $U$ is open and $k \in U$, there exists $r_k>0$ such that $B(k,r_k) \subset U$

I need to prove $B(y,r_y) \subset x+U $ for some $r_y>0$

How to choose $r_y$ and how to move further?

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $r_y=r_k$. If $z \in B(y,r_k)$ then $\|z-y\| <r_k$; this implies that $z-x \in B(k,r_k)$ because $\|(z-x)-(y-x)\| <r_k$ and $y-x=k$. Hence $z=x+(z-x) \in x+U$.

Comment: super sir! I got it...  thank you